# Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::created(), 0 passed (CrudPanel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I updated a backpack project from backpack 4.0 to 4.1 and followed the upgrade guide that is provided on the backpack site. Laravel still runs on 6.x and has not been upgraded lately.
The list and /edit update views are working as intended. Only when trying to open a show view (happens on all models), then the following error occurs:

*Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::created(), 0 passed in /var/www/vendor/backpack/crud/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/CrudPanel.php on line 330 and exactly 1 expected*

I tried to follow the stack trace but I can't find the source that throws the error. I also tried to remove all the methods from one model and just keep construct() and setup() and even then the errors is still thrown.

Edit: The error occurs for all models, this is the code of one random model.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Vereine extends KVUser
{


}
```

```
namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class KVUser extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'user';
    public $incrementing = true;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->creating([$this, 'onCreating']);
        $this->updating([$this, 'onUpdating']);

        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    public static function deleting($callback)
    {
        parent::deleting($callback);
        $callback->update(['deleted' => 1]);
    }


    public function onCreating(\App\Models\KVUser $row)
    {
        // Placeholder for catching any exceptions
        if (!\Auth::user()->id) {
            return false;
        }

        $row->setAttribute('created_id', \Auth::user()->id);
    }

    public function onUpdating(\App\Models\KVUser $row)
    {
        // Placeholder for catching any exceptions
        if (!\Auth::user()->id) {
            return false;
        }

        $row->setAttribute('updated_id', \Auth::user()->id);
    }

}
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests\VereineRequest;
use App\Models\Vereine;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class VereineCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function setup()
    {
        $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Vereine');
        $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/vereine');
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('Verein', 'Vereine');
        $this->crud->setListView('vendor/backpack/crud/vereine/vereine_list');
        $this->crud->setShowView('vendor/backpack/crud/vereine/vereine_show');

    }

}
```

[Screenshot Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHqHq.png)

I would really appreciate some help - thank you!

Comment: Update your question with some code

Answer (score 0):

For clearly to identify error you should attached image. Thanks